# passing( = returning) by reference a vector at the exit of function

Tags: c++, function, return-value, pass-by-reference

is this c++ snipet legal?

```
vector<myType>& aClass::aFunction()
{
    vector<myType> aVec;

    //do stuff

    return aVec;
}
```

then use it in another function as:

```
vector<myType> getVec = aFunction();
```

so basically, I am asking: if I declare `getVec` and get a reference to `aVec` vector data, will the data survive the death of `aFunction()` ?

Comment: If you ask for 'legal', yes, it can be compiled well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No even if the compiler would let it slip, the variable dies with the scope of the function, so you would have a dangling reference and effectively enter Undefined Behaviour state.

Return by value, any descent compiler will perform [(N)RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization). There are some restrictions, so you should alaways check the requirements for your compiler. Especially if there are multiple exit points. But it's best course of action and produces cleanest and fastest code.

Addendum:

It does generate ("just") a warning on both `clang++` and `g++`:

```
luk32@debianvm:~/projects/tests$ g++ ./dangling_reference.cpp 
./dangling_reference.cpp: In function 'std::vector<int>& test()':
./dangling_reference.cpp:6:17: warning: reference to local variable 'v' returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     vector<int> v(10);
                 ^
luk32@debianvm:~/projects/tests$ clang++ ./dangling_reference.cpp 
./dangling_reference.cpp:7:12: warning: reference to stack memory associated with local variable 'v' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]
    return v;
```

However I would advise to mark those warnings as errors, as they nearly always are (by nearly I mean to be on the safe side, I don't know how to return reference to a local variable and not enter UB), and consider adding appropriate switches to the compiler commands. E.g.:

```
g++ -Werror=return-local-addr ./dangling_reference.cpp
clang++ -Werror=return-stack-address ./dangling_reference.cpp
```

IMO, it's a good practice if your project is big enough for anything more than compiling by hand.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's very naughty.  You cannot return a reference to a local variable.

Just pass it back by value.  The compiler should do return-value optimisation for you, so you shouldn't get wasteful copies.

```
vector<myType> aClass::aFunction()
{
    vector<myType> aVec;
    // ...
    return aVec;
}
```

Comment: Well technically you can. Otherwise it would be an error, not a warning. The code is legal but I wonder what use-case does not lead to UB.

Comment: @luk32 My answer was a response to the question "is it legal?" which it is not, as defined by the language.  In your answer, you said that the particular warnings are "nearly always" errors: can you provide an example where returning a reference to a local variable is actually valid?

Comment: Does an illegal code compile? That is the question. I told you already I do not know of a case that does not result in UB, but it does compile. Why would always illegal code compile? Maybe its worth a question of itself. Dunno.

Comment: @luk32 You are confusing what a compiler considers valid with what the C++ standard defines as valid.

Comment: No, I am not confusing anything, I was asking. Those weren't rhetorical questions =). So basically, code that has well defined behaviour (maybe state at sequence points) is only valid from standard's point of view? Is that right? I was seriously wondering if this is a valid question. I am not even sure if the term "valid code" is defined anywhere TBH.

Comment: @luk32 You have a point, but I also think you're missing mine.  The standard outlines this as undefined behaviour, but compilers are free to implement that undefined behaviour in any way they see fit, including the choice to issue a warning instead of an error.  In your answer, you stated that such warnings are "*nearly always* errors", suggesting that you knew of an example where a compiler would be unable to distinguish valid code from UB.  By "valid code", I mean code that does not cause UB.

Comment: I think it's all clear now. It was just a misunderstanding of what "valid" means - either compilable or well-formed. But the compiled program enters UB or not. Compiler doesn't matter. If a compiler issues an error there is no UB, binary won't exist. As to my answer, I made an assumption. If every possible execution path would lead to UB, the compiler should issue an error, thus I *think* there exists a case that the code would be "valid" as per your definition. I might be wrong, but what would be the reason to compile something that is sure to end up as UB? I made an edit to be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

No - the automatic object is destroyed when the function returns, leaving the reference invalid. Doing anything with the reference will give undefined behaviour.

Your compiler should warn you about this; if it doesn't, then turn up your warning level.

Return the vector by value instead. If you're worried about the cost of copying it, move semantics and/or elision will take care of that.